# How to import not standalone components to a standalone component in Angular 14+

Tags: angular, angular14, angular15

I would like to know how to import a non-standalone component into a standalone component, given that the non-standalone component is being declared in an ngModule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a section of the migration documentation about this exact use case: [Using existing NgModules in a standalone component](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#using-existing-ngmodules-in-a-standalone-component).

> When writing a standalone component, you may want to use other components, directives, or pipes in the component's template. Some of those dependencies might not be marked as standalone, but instead declared and exported by an existing `NgModule`. In this case, you can import the `NgModule` directly into the standalone component:
>
> ```js
> @Component({
>   standalone: true,
>   selector: 'photo-gallery',
>   // an existing module is imported directly into a standalone component
>   imports: [MatButtonModule],
>   template: `
>     ...
>     <button mat-button>Next Page</button>
>   `,
> })
> export class PhotoGalleryComponent {
>   // logic
> }
> ```
>
> You can use standalone components with existing `NgModule`-based libraries or dependencies in your template. Standalone components can take full advantage of the existing ecosystem of Angular libraries.

---

If you have `StandaloneComponent` and `NonStandaloneComponent` (which is declared in and exported from `NonStandaloneModule`), then you'd use the `imports` field on the component declaration for `StandaloneComponent`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NonStandaloneModule } from '...';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-standalone',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NonStandaloneModule], // Declares and exports NonStandaloneComponent
  template: `<app-non-standalone></app-non-standalone>` // Use imported as normal
})
export class StandaloneComponent {}
```

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ej6afi?file=src/app/standalone/standalone.component.ts) so you can play with the idea.

Comment: For a reason, my NonStandaloneComponent does not show up. Is there anything else is should consider?

Comment: Do you have a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue? There are many reasons it could be failing. Feel free to look at the StackBlitz linked at the bottom of my answer if you want to compare to your code and spot the difference.

Comment: For me I forgot to export NonStandaloneComponent in NonStandaloneModule