# In standalone mode, how to I import a module in Angular 17?

Tags: angular

everyone. I've noticed that Angular 17 defaults to the standalone mode, which means it doesn't automatically generate the file app.module.ts...
The code below generates an Angular app in standalone mode:

```
ng new project-name
```

The code below generates an angular app in not-standalone mode:

```
ng new project-name --no-standalone
```

However, if I'm working with this new standalone version, could someone guide me on which file to use and how to import a module that was previously imported in the app.module.ts file?

As an example: if I want to import the module **BrowserModule** from **@angular/platform-browser**, do I have to import it in all the components that will use it in the component decorator? Because before, I need to import just at the app.module.ts. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Just import it in the component file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import not standalone components to a standalone component in Angular 14+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75032062/how-to-import-not-standalone-components-to-a-standalone-component-in-angular-14)

Comment: tl;dr - yes, you'll need to import it in each standalone component that uses it. The upside is reduced bundle size for components that don't need to import certain modules. The downside is a little more code for components that do need those modules.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, here is a way to do it:

in your **app.config.ts** in your providers array, use **importProvidersFrom** and then add the module and their (optional) configuration :

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    importProvidersFrom(
      SnackbarModule.forRoot({
        configuration: { configA: 'abc', configB: 'xyz' },
      })
    ),
  ],
};
```

Have a look [here in the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#using-standalone-components-in-ngmodule-based-applications)

Answer (score 3):

In Angular 17's standalone mode, where the traditional app.module.ts file is not automatically generated, you can organize your application without a central module file. Instead, you can import the necessary modules directly into the components where they are needed.

In this code you have a DemoComponent that uses various Angular modules. To import these modules directly into the component, you've done it correctly. Each import statement brings in the necessary module for the component.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.scss']
})

export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor () {}
    ngOnInit (): void {}
}
```

In this case, you don't need a central app.module.ts file. The component itself specifies its dependencies using the imports property of the @Component decorator.

Comment: If there are any reusable components instead of having them in each component is there a way to inject in one file like we have earlier in `module.ts` and use it?